# Size of empty class and empty function?

Tags: c++, c

What will be solution in the following code

```
Class A{}
void func(){}

printf("%d,%d",sizeof(A),sizeof(func));
```

Comment: plz give the reasons for the same also

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?  BTW, you can edit your own question so no need to leave a comment.

Comment: That's not how a class is declared, why are you using `printf` in C++, and `sizeof` isn't guaranteed to fit into `%d` anyway.

Comment: @Prashant: You are using incorrect format specifier in `printf`, using incorrect format specifier in `printf` in UB. You must use `%zu` for `sizeof`

Comment: -1 Please only post code that compiles. Then, whence it compiles and you are able to run it what is the point of your question?

Comment: @all thanks for your replies . But this was one of the questions which was asked to me in an interview which i was not able to answer and i did nt found any answer later on the web . So thought to post it .. I didnt knew that the question asked to me was wrong :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Size of an empty class is non zero(most probably 1), so as to have two objects of the class at different addresses.

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#sizeof-empty explains it better

```
 class A{};
 void func(){}

 std::cout<<sizeof(A)<<std::endl<<sizeof(&func));// prints 1 and 4 on my 32 bit system
```

Answer (score 3):

You are taking the size of a function which cannot be done. You need to preceede the name with a `&` to take the size of a pointer to that function. You also need to cast the `sizeof` value to be of type `int`, which is what `printf` expects for the `d` specifier

```
printf("%d,%d", (int)sizeof(A), (int)sizeof(&func));
```

As for the concrete values ---- It's not known what they are beyond that are greater or equal to `1`. It depends on the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

By `sizeof(func)`, you probably mean `sizeof(&func)`, which is the size of a function pointer in bytes.

As far as what the size of an `A` object is, the standard only says:

> Complete objects and member subobjects of class type shall have nonzero size.

which is qualified by footnote 94:

> Base class subobjects are not so constrained.

The reason for the footnote is to allow for a compiler optimization known as [*empty member optimization*](http://tinf2.vub.ac.be/~dvermeir/c++/emptyopt.html), which is commonly used in template libraries to access routines of a class type (e.g. allocator routines of an allocator class type) without needing a member object of that class type.

Comment: Pointers to differing types aren't guaranteed to be the same size (although they usually are in practice).

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Wow, I was unaware that pointer sizes can be different. Indeed, looking through the C and C++ standards, I can't find anything that forces the sizes of two pointer types to be equal. There was, however, this line from [5.2.10] Reinterpret cast: "A pointer to a function can be explicitly converted to a pointer to a function of a different type". I think that this means the sizes of two *function* pointer types are the same at least.

Comment: One example of where the size of a data pointer and a function pointer *might* differ is on a platform with a Harvard architecture (i.e. separate instruction and data memories).